# How to impose restrictions on a regression using offsets?

Tags: python, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, offset, actuarial-science

An **offset** is a variable that is included in the regression but without coefficient (i.e. the coefficient is fixed at/assumed to be 1). I want to impose restrictions on my regression and I read that it can be done with offsets ([source](https://www.casact.org/sites/default/files/database/forum_09wforum_yan_et_al.pdf)). However, I do not understand how an offset can result in a restriction. Furthermore, I implemented a basic example in python and the other coefficients do not change *(thus if I charge 10% extra on everybody, the total amount also increases with 10% but this should not happen. The other coefficients should adjust accordingly such that the total amount remains similar. The money should just be redistributed among the members)*.

The goal of my regression is to impose a bonus-malus system (i.e. give some people a discount) on a pricing model for insurance.

---

Consider the following (GLM) regression:

$$\log(\text{cost}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1+...+\beta_nX_n + \epsilon$$

where the cost is assumed to follow a Gamma distribution. Suppose that one of the variables $X_i$ is the number of years without a claim. Furthermore, suppose that I want to give everybody that had zero claims last year a discount of 20%. According to the mentioned source, I need to add $\log(0.8)$. To see why this lead to a discount (or surplus?), consider:

$$\text{cost} = e^{\beta_0} \hspace{2mm} e^{X_i} \hspace{2mm}e^{\log(0.8)}$$
$$\hspace{9mm} = 0.8 \hspace{2mm}e^{\beta_0} \hspace{2mm} e^{X_i}$$

However, I am not sure if this is correct. Does this effect all my other coefficient estimates? How do I implement this in python using `statsmodels`? Because the source mentions SAS has support for this by default, using:

[image]

In the SAS code above, we see that the offset is conditionally set (using an `if-statement`). How could I do this in python?

UPDATE: I just learned this is called "relativities" in actuarial science.

Comment: Yes, of course restricting some coefficient estimates will have an impact on all other parameter estimates. If that is the extent of the *statistical* content of your question, it looks like your main request is how to implement this in Python, which is better asked elsewhere.

Comment: However, in my results non of the other coefficients change.

Comment: I know how to implement it in python, but I get strange results. I also want to have an understanding of the math.

Comment: Maybe then show us the strange results, as the  question by now is overly abstract

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the [source](https://www.casact.org/sites/default/files/database/forum_09wforum_yan_et_al.pdf) document you mentioned, I made the following R script. To keep it simple, I used "wage" as dependent, but translation to log(wage) should be obvious, I hope. Explanatory comments are added. Note that the offset variable has to have **different values for specific groups** of cases. I used "gender", so there are two groups. Men have a higher wage, so men get an offset of 10 points, whereas for women the offset is 0 points. Further, "education" is the independent variable. I'm not familiar with Python, so I used R.

```
set.seed(123)

# Generate some data.
gender    <- c(rep(0,10), rep(1,10))
education <- ifelse(gender==0, rnorm(10,0,1), rnorm(10,1,1))
cor(education, gender)

# Generate dependent wage.
wage <- 10 + 10*education + 5*gender + rnorm(20,0,10)

# Suppose we would estimate the influence of education and gender on wage first.
m1 <- lm(wage ~ education + gender)
summary(m1)

# Next, we could eliminate the influence of gender from wage, leading to a new
# variable, wage minus gender, or wage_gender. Men have a 13.657 points 
# higher wage than women, as the summary of m1 shows.
# Also see page 369, 2nd paragraph in the source mentioned.
# Resulting regr. coeff. for m2 below are identical to those in m1.
# Std. errors in m2 are different from those in m1, of course.
# The ifelse below removes the influence of gender from wage. 
wage_gender <- ifelse(gender==1, wage - 13.675, wage)
m2 <- lm(wage_gender ~ education)
summary(m2)


# Above, we estimated the influence of gender. Instead suppose we know beforehand that men
# have a 10 points higher wage than women do. So, we don't have to estimate this difference. 
# Now, we make an offset to specify the difference. 
# So, men have an offset of 10 points and women of 0 points.
# The regression equation would then be: wage = b0 + b1*eduction + offset
# In this equation "offset" should have a regr. coeff. of 1, so this regr. coeff.
# must NOT be estimated. To achieve this, we can simply subtract the offset from both 
# sides of the equation. This is what the ifelse below does. It makes a new 
# variable, wage minus offset, or "wage_offset".
wage_offset <- ifelse(gender==1, wage - 10, wage)
m3 <- lm(wage_offset ~ education)
summary(m3)

# Using wage as dependent gives another regr. coeff. for education and another intercept.
m4 <- lm(wage ~ education)
summary(m4)
```